# Moving average line in line chart Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have built a line chart using two filter conditions and want to include dynamic average line to the visual. Like for example I need to show the average line based on two parameters, first is date i.e. 21st Jan - 25 Jan and the site locations selected, it will only consider average between 21st to 25th Jan and not till 4th of Feb.

The site location will also be selected to count the call volume.

I am struggling to find a way around as I I thought of using SelectedValue or switch method.

Any help will be much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: With the filter applied 21st Jan - 25th Jan, your chart should also show lines for that range, not till 04-Feb right?

Comment: @mkRabbani The chart should only show average value between 21st Jan - 27th Jan as a average line.

Comment: If you apply a filter, whole chart should contain data for that selected range, is not it?

Comment: @mkRabbani So when I use average line from analytics it shows as a straight average line considering 21st Jan - 4th Fen, where as if you select the range 21st Jan - 27th Jan, I want to show average of just the data that's between these two dates and not average for 21st Jan to 4Th Feb

Comment: Got your issue. Create a new measure with AVERAGE. Then add that measure as line value in the chart. Hope this will solve your issue.

Comment: Got your issue. Create a new measure with AVERAGE of your value field. Then add that measure as line value in the chart. Hope this will solve your issue.